# Is there a way to paste in Eclipse without advancing the cursor?

Tags: eclipse, text, cursor, editor, mouse

I want to be able to paste a big chunk of text, then advance down to the next line to paste. When I paste, the cursor ends up at the end of the pasted text.

Answer (score 0):

Your description isn't very clear however I'd suggest once you've pasted the chunk of text use: CTRL + Arrow key (left or right) this moves the cursor to the end of the line in either given direction based on which arrow key you have pressed. Otherwise look into your eclipse settings and you can format the way the IDE reacts after you've pasted a chunk of text.

Comment: That is helpful. I am looking for something that will bring me all the way back to where I started pasting the text - in some cases there are spaces in the pasted text. CTRL arrow helps if the pasted text has no spaces.

Comment: Ah, to do that you must use CTRL+home to go back to the beginning or CTRL-End to go to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, to do that you must use CTRL+home to go back to the beginning or CTRL-End to go to the end.